# Self referencing table not creating index file

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am having some trouble getting a self referencing table to generate the necessary index files for doing searches against my table. My model object is listed below with the annotations sprinkled in for hibernate searches. 
I have trace logging turned on and they don't seem to show anything erroring out, but it only creates :

- segments.gen
- segments_1
- write.lock

I have other indexes set up on less complicated tables working just fine, and from the logs I can see that it actually selected all of the records in the table to index

> "org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) HSEARCH000028: Reindexed 7021
>   entities"

```
 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "node_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
 @Table(name = "gc_node")
 @AttributeOverride(name="nodeType", column = @Column(name="node_type", insertable = false, updatable = false))
 @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
 @Indexed
 public class GcNode {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "NODE_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "NODE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "NODE_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "node_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @DocumentId
    protected Integer nodeId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private GcNode gcParentNode;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "node_type", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 64)
    protected NodeType nodeType;

    @Column(name = "node_name", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 512)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer =       @Analyzer(definition = "lowerCaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer") , store = Store.YES)
    protected String nodeName;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 512)
    protected String description;
...
}
```

here is a bigger section of my trace log for this specific table.

```
dir=MMapDirectory@/private/tmp/lucene/umod/indexes/com.persistence.model.GcNode lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@/tmp/lucene/umod/indexes/com.persistence.model.GcNode
index=
version=4.10.4
matchVersion=4.10.4
analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer
ramBufferSizeMB=16.0
maxBufferedDocs=-1
maxBufferedDeleteTerms=-1
mergedSegmentWarmer=null
readerTermsIndexDivisor=1
termIndexInterval=32
delPolicy=org.apache.lucene.index.KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy
commit=null
openMode=APPEND
similarity=org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity
mergeScheduler=ConcurrentMergeScheduler: maxThreadCount=1, maxMergeCount=2, mergeThreadPriority=-1
default WRITE_LOCK_TIMEOUT=1000
writeLockTimeout=1000
codec=Lucene410
infoStream=org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerInfoStream
mergePolicy=[LogByteSizeMergePolicy: minMergeSize=1677721, mergeFactor=10, maxMergeSize=2147483648, maxMergeSizeForForcedMerge=9223372036854775807, calibrateSizeByDeletes=true, maxMergeDocs=2147483647, maxCFSSegmentSizeMB=8.796093022207999E12, noCFSRatio=0.1]
indexerThreadPool=org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool@5a4993be
readerPooling=false
perThreadHardLimitMB=1945
useCompoundFile=true
checkIntegrityAtMerge=false
writer=org.apache.lucene.util.SetOnce@1d26c013
```

The index that never gets created falls into this

> HSEARCH000226: IFD: init: load commit "segments_1"
>    HSEARCH000226: IFD: now checkpoint "" [0 segments ; isCommit = false]
>    HSEARCH000226: IFD: 0 msec to checkpoint
>    HSEARCH000226: IW: init: create=false

there is no trace from the  'org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.works.AddWorkExecutor'

compared to other indexes that work it looks like this

> HSEARCH000226: IFD: init: load commit "segments_53"
>   HSEARCH000226: IFD: now checkpoint "_hv(4.10.4):C2699" [1 segments ; isCommit = false]
>   HSEARCH000226: IFD: 0 msec to checkpoint
>   HSEARCH000226: IW: init: create=false

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the generated index directory with Luke? How do you know that the index is empty? You could try to enable trace logging for a class like 'org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.works.AddWorkExecutor'. You should get a message for each document added to the Lucene index.

Comment: cool I will try that and see what I find. The reason I know index is empty is that none of the files get created like they do for other tables, and searches come back with no results.